# What are the main elements in a QR code?

Tags: qr-code

I didn't know before about artistic or artwork QR codes, while checking some of these codes, they are completely different from the regular standard QR code, but how is it possible to create this kind of QR code without loosing it's value (the scan result is the same) ?

These QR Codes are the most ones that amazed me:
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/qr-code-artworks/

The only thing in common is the 3 corners, and they're different in style.

So my question is, what are the elements that we should preserve while creating such QR Codes ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qr_code in short: a lot of redundancy gives a lot of artistic freedom. Colors are not important so that you can use fruit or legos or whatever instead of black and white pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important things are:

- Dark-on-light
- Very nearly square modules
- Modest light border
- Substantially preserve the three-finder patterns
- ... and the first line of modules around them, which carries format info
- ... and the bottom-right alignment pattern, is helpful

The rest, the interior, can be substantially obscured and still be readable, certainly with high error correction. But messing with the elements above will tend to make it unreadable much more rapidly